# Compare string equality in Swift: String != (String)

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check if an `item` is not identical to `newItem`. `item` type is String, while `newItem` type is (String) and Xcode complains it cannot compare.

```
for (index, item) in enumerate(components) {
    let newItem = cleanItem(item)
    if newItem != nil && newItem != item {
        // update
    } else {
        // delete item
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `newItem[0]`?

Comment: Can you give us the signature of `cleanItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to change the return type of `cleanItem` from String to String?, as it needs to be allowed to return nil. Then everything works. Appologies for the confusion.

Comment: Since you've resolved this yourself, you might want to either delete the question or at least update the title to be relevant to the actual problem.  It has nothing to do with comparing String to (String) but rather to do with comparing String to nil.

Answer (score 0):

`newItem` is a [Tuple Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448), so you have to extract the value before comparing:

```
if newItem.0 && newItem.0 != item {...}
```

Comment: In swift there's no need for this.  Tuples of a single item are identical to the item itself.  `(String)` is indistinguishable from `String` and they can be directly compared (try it in the Playground :)